# Beaver Builder and Jquery Not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've got the following code running in my functions.php:

```
   wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // Remove WP jQuery version
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', array(), '3.3.1', true );
```

But when I go to the Beaver Builder to edit a page, I click on a module and the module name just repeats and repeats itself for as long as I'm clicking on it.

If I comment out the above code in functions.php, Beaver Builder works fine.

I need to be able to use jQuery with my website, so I'm not sure what to do.  After much searching, Beaver Builder seems to be the best page builder I could find, except for this problem.

Why is this causing a conflict? Does Beaver Builder use its own version of jQuery? Can I disable the above code only when editing a page in Beaver Builder or not?

More info:

I have duplicated the BlankSlate theme to use a starter for my own theme.  I can see above in the functions.php it has the following:

```
function blankslate_load_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('blankslate-style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

But When I look in the `<head>` for the page, it seems that it is loading jQuery  1.12:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://labs.awme.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp" id="jquery-core-js"></script>
```

Here is an output of the jQuery errors I get with my jQuery lines added in (jQuery 3.5.1), whilst using Beaver Builder:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://labs.awme.net/?fl_builder' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js?ver=3.5.1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
header.js?ver=5.5.3:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at header.js?ver=5.5.3:5
(anonymous) @ header.js?ver=5.5.3:5
core.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at core.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at core.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ core.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ core.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
mouse.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at mouse.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at mouse.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ mouse.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ mouse.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
jquery.ui.sortable.js?ver=2.4.0.5:1298 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.ui.sortable.js?ver=2.4.0.5:1298
(anonymous) @ jquery.ui.sortable.js?ver=2.4.0.5:1298
jquery.touch-punch.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:195 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.touch-punch.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:195
(anonymous) @ jquery.touch-punch.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:195
jquery.nanoscroller.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.nanoscroller.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:3
    at jquery.nanoscroller.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:3
(anonymous) @ jquery.nanoscroller.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:3
(anonymous) @ jquery.nanoscroller.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:3
jquery.autoSuggest.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.autoSuggest.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:6
    at jquery.autoSuggest.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:6
(anonymous) @ jquery.autoSuggest.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:6
(anonymous) @ jquery.autoSuggest.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:6
jquery.tiptip.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:188 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.tiptip.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:188
(anonymous) @ jquery.tiptip.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:188
jquery.showhideevents.js?ver=2.4.0.5:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.showhideevents.js?ver=2.4.0.5:15
(anonymous) @ jquery.showhideevents.js?ver=2.4.0.5:15
jquery.simulate.js?ver=2.4.0.5:150 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.simulate.js?ver=2.4.0.5:150
(anonymous) @ jquery.simulate.js?ver=2.4.0.5:150
jquery.validate.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.validate.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:2
    at jquery.validate.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.validate.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.validate.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:2
bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:22
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:22
select2.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at select2.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:2
    at select2.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:2
(anonymous) @ select2.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:2
(anonymous) @ select2.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:2
fl-builder.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at fl-builder.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:1
(anonymous) @ fl-builder.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:1
jquery.fitvids.min.js?ver=1.2:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at jquery.fitvids.min.js?ver=1.2:1
    at jquery.fitvids.min.js?ver=1.2:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.fitvids.min.js?ver=1.2:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.fitvids.min.js?ver=1.2:1
6-layout-draft.js?ver=0500f9d3e595b837108b9f091c0cee8c:107 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at 6-layout-draft.js?ver=0500f9d3e595b837108b9f091c0cee8c:107
(anonymous) @ 6-layout-draft.js?ver=0500f9d3e595b837108b9f091c0cee8c:107
wp-util.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at wp-util.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ wp-util.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
common.js?ver=2.3.7:295 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at common.js?ver=2.3.7:295
(anonymous) @ common.js?ver=2.3.7:295
index.js?ver=2.3.7:151 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js?ver=2.3.7:151)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js?ver=2.3.7:20)
    at index.js?ver=2.3.7:63
    at index.js?ver=2.3.7:66
(anonymous) @ index.js?ver=2.3.7:151
__webpack_require__ @ index.js?ver=2.3.7:20
(anonymous) @ index.js?ver=2.3.7:63
(anonymous) @ index.js?ver=2.3.7:66
wp-backbone.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at wp-backbone.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ wp-backbone.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.23 (media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at r (media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at Object.22 (media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at r (media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
    at media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
23 @ media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
r @ media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
22 @ media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
r @ media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
wp-plupload.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at wp-plupload.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1
(anonymous) @ wp-plupload.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1
mediaelement-migrate.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at mediaelement-migrate.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1
(anonymous) @ mediaelement-migrate.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1
wp-mediaelement.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at wp-mediaelement.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1
(anonymous) @ wp-mediaelement.min.js?ver=5.5.3:1
api-request.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at api-request.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ api-request.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at o (media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at o (media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
    at media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
o @ media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
o @ media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-views.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
media-editor.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at media-editor.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-editor.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mixin' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at o (media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at o (media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
    at media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
o @ media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
o @ media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-audiovideo.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
resizable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at resizable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at resizable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ resizable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ resizable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
draggable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at draggable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at draggable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ draggable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ draggable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
button.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at button.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at button.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ button.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ button.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
position.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at position.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at position.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ position.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ position.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
dialog.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at dialog.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at dialog.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ dialog.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ dialog.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
wpdialog.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at wpdialog.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ wpdialog.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
wplink.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at wplink.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ wplink.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
editor.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (editor.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2)
    at editor.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
    at editor.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ editor.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ editor.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ editor.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
droppable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at droppable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at droppable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ droppable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ droppable.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:103 ReferenceError: FLBuilder is not defined
    at new NotificationsManager (index.js:182)
    at Ag (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:63)
    at Vg (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:89)
    at ph (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:217)
    at lh (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:126)
    at O (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:121)
    at Sb (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:213)
    at wh (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:160)
    at fd (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:160)
    at react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:163
ve @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:103
c.callback @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:114
yg @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:62
xg @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:61
Ti @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:149
unstable_runWithPriority @ react.min.js?ver=16.9.0:26
Ma @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:52
Ia @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:140
Sb @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:213
wh @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:160
fd @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:160
(anonymous) @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:163
kh @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:119
id @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:163
render @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:228
eval @ index.js:43
./src/builder/index.js @ builder.bundle.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:279
__webpack_require__ @ builder.bundle.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:20
(anonymous) @ builder.bundle.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:84
(anonymous) @ builder.bundle.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:87
react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:150 Uncaught ReferenceError: FLBuilder is not defined
    at new NotificationsManager (index.js:182)
    at Ag (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:63)
    at Vg (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:89)
    at ph (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:217)
    at lh (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:126)
    at O (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:121)
    at Sb (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:213)
    at wh (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:160)
    at fd (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:160)
    at react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:163
NotificationsManager @ index.js:182
Ag @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:63
Vg @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:89
ph @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:217
lh @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:126
O @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:121
Sb @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:213
wh @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:160
fd @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:160
(anonymous) @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:163
kh @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:119
id @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:163
render @ react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:228
eval @ index.js:43
./src/builder/index.js @ builder.bundle.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:279
__webpack_require__ @ builder.bundle.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:20
(anonymous) @ builder.bundle.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:84
(anonymous) @ builder.bundle.min.js?ver=2.4.0.5:87
menu.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at menu.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at menu.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ menu.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ menu.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
    at autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @ autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
thickbox.js?ver=3.1-20121105:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at thickbox.js?ver=3.1-20121105:15
(anonymous) @ thickbox.js?ver=3.1-20121105:15
media-upload.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at media-upload.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
(anonymous) @ media-upload.min.js?ver=5.5.3:2
?fl_builder&fl_builder_load_settings_config=modules&ver=431785809:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at ?fl_builder&fl_builder_load_settings_config=modules&ver=431785809:7
(anonymous) @ ?fl_builder&fl_builder_load_settings_config=modules&ver=431785809:7
?fl_builder&fl_builder_load_settings_config=1&ver=787727100:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at ?fl_builder&fl_builder_load_settings_config=1&ver=787727100:7
```

Comment: Without seeing an error message to debug we can only guess at the issue. ***However***, you're including the 'slim' branch of jQuery which has a lot of key functionality removed and may be causing issues. Try adding the full version of jQuery instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There are a bunch of jquery errors, none of which are very helpful.  I dont mind posting them though, i'll try the full version first.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan With the full version (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js)  Beaver Builder editor just refuses to load, I can't make any changes to the page at all

Comment: Could you please post the errors, it may offer some clues